# prefer high index number than lower one in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, integer

Assuming that I have these two **sorted** arrays with 5 cells:

The numbers in the array are between 2 and 14 ( 2 and 14 included and they are integers )

Now, I need to give a rank to each array from [0,100] when the lowest array will be:

[2,2,2,2,2] and the highest will be [14,14,14,14,14]

Now the thing is: the index is important so for example if we take a look at this these arrays:

1) [2,2,2,2,10]

2) [8,8,8,8,9]

So the 1st one is better than the the 2nd and will get an higher score.

And if there's a tie in the index ( from right to left ) for example:

1) [3,4,5,10,13]

2) [3,4,7,10,13]

So index numbers: 3 and 4 are the same, but since 7 is higher than 5. so in that case the 2nd array will have an higher score.

I'm struggling with the math, I mean I want to do it efficient, now I can do something like:

2^array[i] but it won't be efficient, so the main thing I managed to do is

```
double rank = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    rank += (double)array[i] / 14 + i;
}
```

because if array[i] can be between 2 and 14, so  1/7 <= array[i]/14 <= 1
so I thought that if I'll add + i each iteration, the next iteration will be greater than all the previous ones, but it's mistake.

I'll be glad for some help in here.

Comment: Why is this tagged python if your code is in c#?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to achieve and your example with `[14,14,14,14,2]` is not correct - array is not sorted

Comment: @ingvar Sorry I fixed the example.
DanielMesejo, sorry it was a mistake that already being fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are essentially describing a base-13 number. Each "digit" (array position) represents one of 13 distinct, ordered values.

You can calculate a ranking by converting the array to a 5 digit, base 13 value:

- Subtract 2 from each array element's value to normalize the element value to the range 0..12.
- Give each array element a score = (normalized element value) * (13 raised to the array index power). 1)
- Add up the scores.

1) Or raised to Array.Length - array index, depending on which side of the array should be the least significant.

Comment: Amazing answer! thanks a lot, only in retrospect I notice that it is really compatible with the base change problem and the sum of them.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was this an online code challenge? It has that feel to it.

Comment: Actually I needed that to implement a poker algorithm, so higher cards will be preferred than lowers, and you gave really brilliant answer. sometimes these sort of "code challenges" can be implemented in the real world code, thanks once again.

Comment: That's why base 13 felt somehow familiar... I wrote poker algorithms myself some years ago :-)